# How to change the url after forwarding a servlet to jsp page?

Tags: java, jsp, url, servlets, forward

I have a search.jsp page that has some html content and a form. When the form is submitted, there is a servlet handle the form data and forward the results to the search.jsp page. However, the url in the browser after processing the form is changed to the servlet name:

`http://localhost:8080/MyProject/SearchServlet`

not the search.jsp page:

```
http://localhost:8080/MyProject/Search.jsp
```

How I can change the url to the search.jsp? In other words, I just want to refresh the search.jsp page to display the results in the same page. How I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that by forwarding the request: you need to "tell" the browser to generate a new http request by using the response.sendRedirect() method.

Now the question is why do you want the url bar to display the name of the Jsp?

Hiding the real destination path is a desired feature when forwarding requests: users do not need to know the server side redirects (that's how they are also called) happening in your web app.
Think about it: to carry out its tasks a servlet potentially can forward the request a number of times before getting to the final destination: you don't want the url bar to change each and every single time.

Give a fancier name to your servlet like: "Search" rather than "SearchServlet" so that users will know they are on the search page of your web application and not in the "SearchServlet" page.

In addition to that, if you visit any professional website, you will hardly ever see the .jsp or .html or .php extension on the address bar. While that is not a requirement or specification and you are free to do so, I believe the first approach is best practice (it looks even better to me honestly). There is even a folder WEB-INF whose purpose is to hide your .jsp pages from direct access via url bar.

What I like doing is having a servlet as the landing-welcome page of the web app, that will be responsible to forward and redirect requests based on the user input and the inner working of the application.

Now back to your final request (pun intended)

"In other words, I just want to refresh the search.jsp page to display the results in the same page. How I can do that?"

What I would do is:

1. redirect the user to the "Search" servlet from the welcome/home servlet.
2. In the doGet method of the Search servlet I would forward the request to the search.jsp page (you could set attributes before forwarding if you need to).
3. In the search.jsp I would set the action attribute of the form to "Search" (the name of the servlet) and the method to POST.
4. In the doPost method of the Search servlet you would implement whatever logic you wish to implement and finally forward the request to the search.jsp

After hitting the search button (and even after the submit button is clicked) what the user will see on the address bar is simply

```
http://localhost:8080/MyProject/Search
```

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the same search.jsp for searching and well as showing the result? It is possible to use the same jsp to perform both the functions but it's easier and desirable to make another jsp which will only show the results.

If you are not able to see the results on search.jsp then make sure that you are setting the proper response in the Servlet class before forwarding it to the jsp and also whether you are reading the response sent by the Servlet class properly in the jsp.

If you want, the page to not refresh at all, then go for AJAX.